# Submit form to fill up the last recent ID row [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have this table:

```
------------------
 ID  |    Car    |
------------------
 25  |    Honda  |
 ..  |     ...   |
 ..  |     ...   |
 ..  |     ...   |
 123 |    Toyota |
------------------
```

How to start fill in at row 124 instead of filling up row 1 til row 24 first? Assuming the `ID` is auto-incremental value.

Actual problem: my form method post fill up row with `ID = 1` instead of `ID = 124`

Answer (score 0):

If you want preserve  the id from 1 to  123  for reserved use and start insert new value for 124,  you could set the initial value for AUTO_INCREMENT

```
ALTER TABLE your_table  AUTO_INCREMENT=123;
```

or directly in your create table

```
CREATE TABLE your_table () AUTO_INCREMENT = 123;
```

then if you insert a value with a null value for id, the auto increment should be 124

```
insert into your_table (car) values ('my_124 car');
```